# Split Strings in Java

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm trying to clean up this very Noisy (due to OCR) dataset of names and email addresses and one problem is multiple names in one entry, for example

```
"Fenner, Robert: Fishbume, Howard" should be "Fenner, Robert" and "Fishbume, Howard"

or "Fendrich, Karen N., Ricci, Vincent" should be "Fendrich, Karen N." and "Ricci, Vincent"
```

How could I use regex to find entries where to strings are separated by a comma or colon, that are themselves separated by a comma and then split the string?

other variations of the problem:

```
"'Emily Phaup ' Ryan, Thomas M" -> "Emily Phaup", "Ryan, Thomas M"

"A Lilly, Alisia Rudd, Andrew McComb, Daniel Lisbon, David Compton"
->"A Lilly", "Alisia Rudd", "Andrew McComb", "Daniel Lisbon", "David Compton"

"Abigail.Perlmangus.pm.com  Jay.Poole@us.pm.com" -> "Abigail.Perlmangus.pm.com", "Jay.Poole@us.pm.com"
```

and a couple more.

I know that it might not be possible to separate all of these occurences (especially without accidentally sepperating correct names) but separating some of them would definitely help

EDIT: I guess my question is a bit too broad, so I'll narrow it down a bit:
Is there a way to find Strings with the format `"string1,string2, string3,string4"` (the strings can contain any kind of chars and whitespaces) and split them into two seperate strings: `"string1,string2" and "string3,string4"`?
and could someone give me some pointers on how to do it, because I'm quite inexperienced with regex.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please post clear examples of possible scenarios and try to post your attempts.

Comment: You should not only post your input, but also the expected output! So what you want to geht.

Answer (score 1):

Well i would have try something like that

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

    String regex = "(\\w+(,|:|$)\\s*\\w+)(,|:|$)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    String [] tests = {
            "Fenner, Robert: Fishbume, Howard"
            ,"string1, string2, string3, string4"
    };

    for (String test : tests) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }

    }
}
```

Output :

```
Fenner, Robert
Fishbume, Howard
string1, string2
string3, string4
```

This won't work for all your cases, but answer to your last edit

---

What i've done, is searching any word characters (\w+) followed by either , or : or being at the end of string. Followed by any space and other word characters followed again by , or : or end of line.

---

Regex detail

```
(\w+(,|:|$)\s*\w+)(,|:|$)
1st Capturing group (\w+(,|:|$)\s*\w+)
    \w+ match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
2nd Capturing group (,|:|$)
    1st Alternative: ,
        , matches the character , literally
    2nd Alternative: :
        : matches the character : literally
    3rd Alternative: $
        $ assert position at end of the string
\s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\w+ match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
3rd Capturing group (,|:|$)
    1st Alternative: ,
        , matches the character , literally
    2nd Alternative: :
        : matches the character : literally
    3rd Alternative: $
        $ assert position at end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

My honest recommendation is to take a representative sample to an online Regex calculator and play with it until you can stomach the output.

As you've noted, the input is not regular enough to really harness Regex. But you may be able to hack it down a little bit at least. There's probably not gonna be a one true perfect answer to that nastiness.

Comment: alright, I'll try that. Got any tips on how to find something in this format: `"string1,string2, string3,string4"`?